# XML pullparser exception unexpected token

Tags: android, ksoap2

I am using ksoap2 library to invoke a web service method. the following code is used for it

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(SOAP_ACTION, SOAP_METHOD);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            // Use this to add parameters
            request.addProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = false;

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_URL);

        // this is the actual part that will call the webservice

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

and it gives me XML pull parser exception "unexpected token(position:TEXT". But i have used the same library to invoke another method in the same service url without any errors.
MY android os version is 4.0

Comment: Please see the answer for the [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254089/kxmlparser-throws-unexpected-token-exception-at-the-start-of-rss-pasing). In gist- there are some invisible byte marks that choke the pull parser